# Cloning a Django project has now meant that my CSS file isn't being found

Tags: python, django

I have been writing a project for a course I am doing but unfortunately the IDE I was using ran out of space and I had to start afresh by cloning my project to a new environment. My old environment had a CSS file that was being picked up correctly.

When I cloned the project an extra base directory was created and now I have noticed that my CSS file isn't being picked up.

I don't get any errors, but nothing in my CSS is being used.

I assume that since it used to work it should be fairly simple to sort out but I cannot see what the problem is.

If anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated.

This is my header in base.html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>IssueTracker{% block page_title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c46cd61739.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    {% block head_js %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        Stripe.publishableKey = '{{ publishable }}';
    //]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/stripe.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
</head>
```

This is the settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for issuetracker project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import dj_database_url
if os.path.exists('env.py'):
    import env

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [os.environ.get('AWSC9_HOST'), '3231d88fef004534aa79ab40a77c1898.vfs.cloud9.us-east-2.amazonaws.com', 'dm-issuetracker.herokuapp.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_forms_bootstrap',
    'accounts',
    'tickets',
    'checkout',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'issuetracker.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'issuetracker.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
#     }
# }
# DATABASES = {
#     'default': dj_database_url.parse(os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'))
# }

if "DATABASE_URL" in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.parse(os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'))
    }
else:
    print("Postgres URL not found, using sqlite instead")
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'accounts.backends.EmailAuth'
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), )

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE = os.getenv('STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE')
STRIPE_SECRET = os.getenv(('STRIPE_SECRET'))

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MESSAGE_STORAGE = "django.contrib.messages.storage.session.SessionStorage"

EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get("EMAIL_ADDRESS")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("EMAIL_PASSWORD")
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Here is a screen print of my directory structure. Originally, before the clone the issuetracker5 directory did not exist, it started at issuetracker:

[image: Directory structure]

Comment: What is the response when you browse to the url for the css file in your browser?

Comment: It is picking up an older version of the CSS. I am making changes and saving the file but my changes are not being displayed.

Comment: If this is local, try another browser (or clear the cache). If this is remotely, did you re-run `manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: Running that command solved the problem! Many thanks for your help, it is greatly appreciated.